# How to execute a PHP program in the form of a string inside node.js?

Tags: php, node.js, express

I get a PHP string from the frontend and I just want to execute it and get the stdout and stderr.

This is what I tried:

```
const runner = require('child_process');
runner.exec('php ' + phpString, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  // ...
});
```

but this requires the PHP code to be in a file because it needs the path as an argument which leads to a PHP file. But writing the `phpString` to a file and then executing it seems unnecessary so is there a way I can directly execute the string?

Comment: why do you want do this or allow this? Allowing the client to send arbitrary code which you then execute without validation seems like a good way to invite security problems.

Comment: @ADyson I'm just creating an app where users can execute programs in different languages. Kind of a personal project.

Comment: ok but still if you let other people use it, then it puts your server at risk.

Comment: @ADyson - Okay, If I want to validate the string so that it doesn't contain anything risky I'm guessing that would be hard.

Comment: Yes, it would be. Which is why the whole scheme is a very bad idea, unless the only person who's ever going to use it is you (and you add some security to make sure of that), or you create a heavily sandboxed environment where only certain commands can be executed which cannot possibly cause damage to the server - something like in the sandbox sites you see online (such as [this one](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)) where a lot of commands are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-r` flag of `PHP` cli for that.

```
const runner = require('child_process');
const phpString = `'echo "hi";'`
runner.exec('php -r ' + phpString, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
     console.log(stdout) // hi
});
```

Although I would use `execFile/spawn` instead, to avoid scaping the arguments

```
const runner = require('child_process');
const phpString = `echo "hi";` // without <?php
runner.execFile('php', ['-r', phpString], (err, stdout, stderr) => {
   console.log(stdout) // hi
});
```

---

If you want to use `<?php` tags, you should use `spawn` and write to `stdin`. This is the best approach in my opinion.

```
const php = runner.spawn('php');
const phpString = `<?php echo "hi";?>` // you can use <?php

// You can remove this if you want output as Buffer
php.stdout.setEncoding('utf8') 
php.stdout.on('data', console.log)
php.stderr.on('data', console.error)

php.stdin.write(phpString)
php.stdin.end()
```

---

Have in mind that allowing users to execute code on your server is **not** recommended.

Comment: Yes, the `php -r` flag only works without `<?php` tags. But it isn't hard to remove them.

Comment: Okay I'll first remove them using javascript and then pass it.

Comment: Check updated answer, you can use `<?php` tags using `.spawn`

Comment: Hi, Marcos, the updated answer works fine but If there are any syntax errors in the program I see that they are being logged because of `php.stdout.on('data', console.log)` so if I want to separate the stdout and stderr using the last approach what can I do?

Comment: yeah, I didn't show error handling, I left that to you, but I'll update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213686/discussion-between-ramesh-reddy-and-marcos-casagrande).

Comment: Can you take a look at the new messages I sent in chat?

Answer (score 2):

Marcos already gave a valid and correct answer, I would just like to add that you can also pipe the `php`-code to the `php`-executable:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const phpString = '<?php echo 1; ?>';

exec(`echo "${phpString}" | php`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(stdout); // prints "1"
});
```

Comment: Actually this is only working if I try this on a string like this `echo 1;` but if I use a string that has `<?php echo 1; ?>` it's giving me an error. This is the error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in Command line code on line 1`.

Comment: You need to make sure that the php opening/closing tags are only set once. Your error message seems like they are set twice.

Comment: No, I verified it as Marcos said below I think we can't use those tags in this way.